# c#: sql request performance issue

Tags: c#, sql, performance

I am accessing a database with c#. Now I have to make some calculations with data that I get from some tables and write it into other existing tables. This works quite good in most cases, but for complex operations it takes a huge amount of time. Now I want to know what would be good practice to speed up my querys and get to my results. Here is what I do:

1. I get a data table that contains 3 values (lom(unique id), laktanfang, laktende) that contains about 700 rows.
2. For each row in this table I do a query from another table. This results in another data table containing 2 values (lom(unique id), behanddatum)
3. Now I check if the the value of behanddatum is in between laktanfang and laktende --> yes: Add the row to the data table that gets returned by my function --> no: go on
4. In the end I have to get the number of positive results from my data table

Here is the code I currently use. I hope it's not too confusing.

```
public DataTable HoleAbgeschlosseneLaktationenMitDiagnosen(DateTime daAnfang, DateTime daEnde, string[] stDiagnosen = null)
    {            
        DataTable dtRet = new DataTable();
        dtRet.Columns.Add("lom", typeof(string));
        dtRet.Columns.Add("laktanfang", typeof(DateTime));
        dtRet.Columns.Add("laktende", typeof(DateTime));

        DataTable dtAbgänge = HoleAbgängeVonEinzeltierZugang(daEnde, daAnfang);
        //Abgeschlossene Laktationen für abgegegangene Tiere
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtAbgänge.Rows)
        {
            if (dr != null)
            {
                DateTime daAbgangsdatum = dr.Field<DateTime>("abgangsdatum");
                string stLom = dr.Field<string>("lom");
                DataTable dtKalbungVorAbgang = HoleLetzteKalbungFuerTier(stLom, daAbgangsdatum);

                if (dtKalbungVorAbgang.Rows.Count > 0 && !dtKalbungVorAbgang.Rows[0].IsNull("kalbedatum"))
                {
                    DateTime daKalbedatum = (DateTime)dtKalbungVorAbgang.Rows[0]["kalbedatum"];
                    int inLaktation = (int)dtKalbungVorAbgang.Rows[0]["laktation"];

                    if (PrüfeObDiagnoseInZeitraumAufgetreten(stLom, stDiagnosen, daKalbedatum, daAbgangsdatum) || stDiagnosen == null)
                    {
                        DataRow drLaktAbgang = dtRet.NewRow();
                        drLaktAbgang["lom"] = stLom;
                        drLaktAbgang["laktanfang"] = daKalbedatum;
                        drLaktAbgang["laktende"] = daAbgangsdatum;
                        dtRet.Rows.Add(drLaktAbgang);
                    }

                    if (daKalbedatum >= daAnfang && inLaktation > 1)
                    {
                        DataTable dtVorherigeKalbung = HoleLetzteKalbungFuerTier(stLom, daKalbedatum.AddDays(-1));
                        DateTime daVorhKalbung = (DateTime)dtVorherigeKalbung.Rows[0]["kalbedatum"];

                        if (dtVorherigeKalbung.Rows.Count > 0 && !dtVorherigeKalbung.Rows[0].IsNull("kalbedatum"))
                        {
                            if (PrüfeObDiagnoseInZeitraumAufgetreten(stLom, stDiagnosen, daKalbedatum, daAbgangsdatum) || stDiagnosen == null)
                            {
                                DataRow drLaktVorhKalbung = dtRet.NewRow();
                                drLaktVorhKalbung["lom"] = stLom;
                                drLaktVorhKalbung["laktanfang"] = daVorhKalbung;
                                drLaktVorhKalbung["laktende"] = daKalbedatum;
                                dtRet.Rows.Add(drLaktVorhKalbung);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }                
        }          

        DataTable dtKalbungen = HoleKalbungenFürLebendTiere(daEnde, daAnfang);
        //Abgeschlossene Laktationen für lebende Tiere
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtKalbungen.Rows)
        {
            DateTime daKalbedatumLetzte = dr.Field<DateTime>("kalbedatum");
            string stLom = dr.Field<string>("lom");
            int inLaktation = dr.Field<int>("laktation");

            if (inLaktation > 1)
            {
                DataTable dtKalbungVorErster = HoleLetzteKalbungFuerTier(stLom, daKalbedatumLetzte.AddDays(-1));

                if (!dtKalbungVorErster.Rows[0].IsNull("kalbedatum"))
                {
                    DateTime daKalbedatum = (DateTime)dtKalbungVorErster.Rows[0]["kalbedatum"];

                    if (PrüfeObDiagnoseInZeitraumAufgetreten(stLom, stDiagnosen, daKalbedatum, daKalbedatumLetzte) || stDiagnosen == null)
                    {
                        DataRow drLaktKalbung = dtRet.NewRow();
                        drLaktKalbung["lom"] = stLom;
                        drLaktKalbung["laktanfang"] = daKalbedatum;
                        drLaktKalbung["laktende"] = daKalbedatumLetzte;
                        dtRet.Rows.Add(drLaktKalbung);
                    }                      

                    inLaktation = (int)dtKalbungVorErster.Rows[0]["laktation"];

                    if (daKalbedatum >= daAnfang && inLaktation > 1)
                    {
                        DataTable dtVorherigeKalbung = HoleLetzteKalbungFuerTier(stLom, daKalbedatum.AddDays(-1));

                        if (dtVorherigeKalbung.Rows.Count > 0 && !dtVorherigeKalbung.Rows[0].IsNull("kalbedatum"))
                        {
                            DateTime daVorhKalbung = (DateTime)dtVorherigeKalbung.Rows[0]["kalbedatum"];

                            if (PrüfeObDiagnoseInZeitraumAufgetreten(stLom, stDiagnosen, daVorhKalbung, daKalbedatum) || stDiagnosen == null)
                            {
                                DataRow drLaktVorhKalbung = dtRet.NewRow();
                                drLaktVorhKalbung["lom"] = stLom;
                                drLaktVorhKalbung["laktanfang"] = daVorhKalbung;
                                drLaktVorhKalbung["laktende"] = daKalbedatum;
                                dtRet.Rows.Add(drLaktVorhKalbung);
                            }                                
                        }
                    }
                }
            }                
        }

        return dtRet;
    }

    private bool PrüfeObDiagnoseInZeitraumAufgetreten(string stLom, string[] stDiagnosen, DateTime daAnfang, DateTime daEnde)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DataTable dtDiagnosenGefunden = new DataTable();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT diagnose " +
                          "FROM b_milch_hms_diagnose " +
                          "WHERE lom=@lom AND behanddatum >= @datumanfang AND behanddatum <= @datumende";

        if (stDiagnosen != null)
        {
            int i = 0;

            foreach (string st in stDiagnosen)
            {
                if (st != "")
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                        cmd.CommandText += " AND diagnose LIKE @gesuchte_diagnose" + i;
                    else
                        cmd.CommandText += " OR diagnose LIKE @gesuchte_diagnose" + i;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gesuchte_diagnose" + i, st + "%");
                }

                i++;
            }
        }

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lom", stLom);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datumanfang", daAnfang);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datumende", daEnde);

        dtDiagnosenGefunden = w_milch.FühreSqlAus(cmd);
        if (dtDiagnosenGefunden.Rows.Count > 0 && !dtDiagnosenGefunden.Rows[0].IsNull("diagnose"))
            return true;

        return false;

    }
```

I hope you can help me to improve this function to work more efficient or at least give me some hints.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have created a [N+1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem) problem. One way to solve this would be to change `HoleAbgängeVonEinzeltierZugang` so that it [joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) in the data you need from the  `b_milch_hms_diagnose` table.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 4.0, you can also try to use parallel foreach and see the impact it has on the loop execution time. (This is a more general advice you could apply to many examples)

```
    _dtAbgänge.Rows.AsParallel().ForEach(dr=>
                                              {
                                                  //do work
                                              });
```